# How to style a link inside a table with Bootstrap's helping classes?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, html-table

I´m sure it's an easy issue to solve but I'm unable to find the right way to do it.

I have a web with Bootstraps (hero-bootstrap template).

I have a link in a table and I'm unable to apply a helping class like "text-success" to the link.

Check the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/9dt5zo74/2/

```
<div class="table-responsive">
    <table class="table table-condensed table-hover table-striped text-center">
    <thead>
    <tr class="active">
    <th class="text-center">text</th>
    <th class="text-center">text</th>
    <th class="text-center">text</th>
    <th class="text-center">text</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>

            <tr>

            <td><a class="text-success" href="#">something should work and it doesnt</a></td>
            <td>text</td>
            <td>text</td>
            <td>text</td>
            </tr>

    </tbody>
    </table>
    </div>
<p class="text-success">that works</p>
```

As you will see, the class works for elements outside the table.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

style in line 6400

```
table a:not(.btn),
.table a:not(.btn) {
     color: #fff;
     text-decoration: underline;
}
```

gets higher priority